# How to get dynamic type property?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamictype

I have a project that I should place some code in other layer and because of this I should transfer a linq query to method.
This code:

```
var HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService = App.Api.HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService.Instance().Data();
        var SMSGroupMemberService = App.Api.SMSGroupMemberService.Instance().Data();
        return (from x in SMSGroupMemberService
                where Recivers.Contains(x.GroupID)
                join v in HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService on x.Pers_Code equals v.Pers_Code
                select new { Pers_Code = (int)x.Pers_Code, Tel = v.Tel }).ToList();
```

I converted up code to:

```
public dynamic HRPersonnelContactInfoTelMethod(List<int> Recivers)
    {
        var HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService = App.Api.HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService.Instance().Data();
        var SMSGroupMemberService = App.Api.SMSGroupMemberService.Instance().Data();
        return (from x in SMSGroupMemberService
                where Recivers.Contains(x.GroupID)
                join v in HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService on x.Pers_Code equals v.Pers_Code
                select new { Pers_Code = (int)x.Pers_Code, Tel = v.Tel }).ToList();
    }
```

but when I use it in foreach

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Pers_Code'

Use it like this:

```
var q = App.Api.HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService.Instance().HRPersonnelContactInfoTelMethod(Recivers);
        foreach (var item in Recivers)
        {
            var res = App.Api.SMSMessageGroupService.Instance().AddOrUpdate(null, MessageId, item);
        }
        foreach (var z in q)
        {
            string SendNumber = Number[1].Trim().Substring(0, 3) == "+98" ? Number[1].Trim() : "+98" + Number[1].Trim();
            var res = App.Api.SMSMessageLogService.Instance().AddOrUpdate(null, MessageId, (int)z.Pers_Code, z.Tel.ToString(),
                 0, int.Parse(ddlSMSWorkingGroups.SelectedValue.ToString()), (int)z.Pers_Code, SendNumber, 0);
            send.SendSMS("nazmaran", "qwerty", SendNumber, "09122596898", txtPredefinedRemarks.Text);
        }
```

Comment: add some code about how do you use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would never use dynamic to return the result of a linq query that uses anonymous types to project the results. Instead, I would create a class that holds the results:

```
public class SomeName
{
   public int Pers_Code { set; get; }
   public string /* Change to Correct Type */ Tel { set; get;}
}
```

Usage:

```
public List<SomeName> HRPersonnelContactInfoTelMethod(List<int> Recivers)
{
   var HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService = App.Api.HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService.Instance().Data();
   var SMSGroupMemberService = App.Api.SMSGroupMemberService.Instance().Data();
   return (from x in SMSGroupMemberService
           where Recivers.Contains(x.GroupID)
           join v in HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService on x.Pers_Code equals v.Pers_Code
           select new SomeName() { Pers_Code = (int)x.Pers_Code, Tel = v.Tel }).ToList();
}
```

Creating a type to hold the results is nothing compared to the complexity of used dynamic.

Comment: Its not work throw :Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int Pers_Code, string Tel>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<App.Api.HRPersonnelContactInfoTelService.SomeName>'

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that .NET can not perform dynamic typization with `var` and iterator through dynamic, that presents a list of object.

So, when you are creating variable with `var` - .NET can not predict a return type and creates a new `object` variable, as every type is inherited from `object`.

However, implementing a return type as `dynamic` is a bad practice - possible errors can not be found until you does not call this method. So, implement a usage of another class, as @user3185569 suggested.